# OptaPlanner CVRPTW - continuous deliveries

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I'm new to OptaPlanner, and I'm trying to configure it in my project to solve a CVRPTW problem. My current configuration is very similar to the example you can find in the source code of the project, but my requirements are different.
My application receives continuously delivery requests where:

- Average service duration is 5 minutes
- DueTime - ReadyTime = 10 minutes
- Average distance (in time) between locations is about 2,5 minutes
- Only 1 depot

My idea is to re-run the solving algorithm every time a new request is received. This is necessary for me to understand if the request is feasible or if it needs to be shifted forward or backward in time.
If you consider the following problem statement (locations omitted, but fairly equidistant from the depot's location):

```
CUST_ID READY_TIME  DUE_TIME    SERV_DUR        DEMAND  
1       12:45:00    12:55:00    00:05:00        1       
2       12:35:00    12:45:00    00:05:00        8       
3       12:25:00    12:35:00    00:05:00        5       
4       13:25:00    13:35:00    00:05:00        5
```

Considering there are 2 vehicles available, both with a capacity of 10, I get the following solution (timetable for each vehicle):

```
**Vehicle 1 Capacity 10 - delivery sequence starting from Depot [1]**
Cust[3]     D: 5    Ar.T: 12:25:00  Ap.T: 12:23:08  Prev.D: 00:01:52    Next.D: 00:03:46
Cust[4]     D: 5    Ar.T: 12:33:56  Ap.T: 12:30:00  Prev.D: 00:03:56    Next.D: --:--:--

**Vehicle 2 Capacity 10 - delivery sequence starting from Depot [1]**
Cust[2]     D: 8    Ar.T: 12:35:00  Ap.T: 12:33:03  Prev.D: 00:01:57    Next.D: 00:03:05
Cust[1]     D: 1    Ar.T: 12:42:47  Ap.T: 12:40:00  Prev.D: 00:02:47    Next.D: --:--:--
```

Where D is Demand, Ar.T is Arrival Time, Ap.T is Approaching Time (time when it's necessary to leave previous location to arrive punctual to the selected one), Prev.D is the distance (in time) from the previous location and Next.D is the distance (in time) from the following location.

As you can see, the customer 4 receives the delivery too much early (arrival time is 12:33:56, while ready time is 13:25:00). I understand the rule *arrivalBeforeReadyTime* is an extra soft constraint, but I would expect that the planner suggest me to deliver to customer 4 using a reserved delivery. Setting the rule *arrivalBeforeReadyTime* as an extra hard constraint, most of the time I get the following exception:

```
org.drools.core.RuntimeDroolsException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.base.accumulators.SumAccumulateFunction.reverse(SumAccumulateFunction.java:85)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. When I get the exception above, should I have to catch it as "problem unsolved"? Or do I have to tune my configuration? Is it something that I should not get?
2. How should I manage continuous deliveries scenario? Should I have to define different large time-windows to solve independently? But how to define boundaries of these windows? And how to manage deliveries planned across boundaries? (this solution seems not correct to me)

**EDIT 1:**

Updating OptaPlanner version from the 6.0.0.CR3 to 6.0.0.CR4-Pre1 solved the NullPointerException.
The documentation is clear about real-time planning and I was already considering to run my planner in real-time mode. But since in the example above the result was not good, I was trying to understand what else I could have done to manage that situation.
I swiched the rule *arrivalBeforeReadyTime* from soft to hard constraint, now I don't get the NullPointerException, time-schedule seems to be managed properly, and the result is the following (for example):

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

```
CUSTID  RTIME         DTIME           SERVDUR         DEMAND 
1       12:45:00      12:55:00        00:05:00        5      
2       12:35:00      12:45:00        00:05:00        3      
3       12:25:00      12:35:00        00:05:00        10     
4       14:25:00      14:35:00        00:05:00        2
```

**SOLUTION**

```
**Vehicle 1       Capacity 10 - delivery sequence starting from Depot [1]**
Cust[3]   D: 10   Ar.T: 12:25:00  Ap.T: 12:23:08     Prev.D: 00:01:52    Next.D: 00:02:26
Cust[2]   D: 3    Ar.T: 12:32:26  Ap.T: 12:30:00     Prev.D: 00:02:26    Next.D: 00:03:05
Cust[1]   D: 5    Ar.T: 12:42:47  Ap.T: 12:40:00     Prev.D: 00:02:47    Next.D: --:--:--

**Vehicle 2       Capacity 10 - delivery sequence starting from Depot [1]**
Cust[4]   D: 2    Ar.T: 14:25:00  Ap.T: 14:22:53     Prev.D: 00:02:07    Next.D: --:--:--
```

As you can see, the 1st delivery is not feasible, since the sum of the demands overflows the vehicle's capacity. Should I assume it to be correct? I mean, in that case a good solution would be to use both vehicles to manage customers 1,2,3. I'm using the same configuration of the example, with vehicleCapacity as a hard constraint. Moreover, customer 2 and 1 are served before ready time, also if I'm using a hard constraint for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, first read the documentation on [repeated planning](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#repeatedPlanning) in general and more specifically about [real-time planning](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#realTimePlanning) specifically.

You can try real-time planning out in the demo by **clicking anywhere on the VRP map while it's solving**.

1. That exception is a bug (in your code or ours). It should never happen. Read the warnings in the docs section referenced above. If you followed those, and believe the bug is not in your code, then please [file a jira](http://www.optaplanner.org/code/issueTracker.html).
2. Let me know if the docs don't answer this question clearly.

PS: make sure you're using 6.0.0.CR4. Drools <= CR3 had a bug related to shadow variables in VRP timewindows.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey for your quick reply. Please read **EDIT 1** in my post.

Comment: In CR4 the VRPTW example changed IIRC that the "served before readyTime" inflicts waiting, but no hard or soft penalty (because the VRP research academics defined the problem as such). If your business does want to penalize it, add the constraint again.

Comment: PS: could you summarize the question a bit more? And handle 1 question per thread pls :)